# Spring Hibernate SessionFactory.getCurrentSession in multithreaded environment

Tags: multithreading, spring, hibernate, sessionfactory

I have written a batch application which spawns multiple threads to read assigned files and save records to database. The architecture uses Spring context and Hibernate.

Transaction is managed by Spring and I am using `SessionFactory.getCurrentSession` to get a session to perform a save operation for each thread.

Consider that I have a generic DAO that handles get, save, update operations and a facade to hide Hibernate implementation, how can I be assured that two threads when invoking `SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` are getting their dedicated Session object to perform DB operations.

I found a post in StackOverflow where someone recommended not to use `current_session_context_class=thread` when using spring managed transaction. what is the default implementation used by Spring for `current_session_context_class` property?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

As of Spring 2.0 Spring integrates with hibernate throuhg its own implementation(s) of the [`CurrentSessionContext`](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/javadoc/7.1.2.Final/org/hibernate/context/spi/CurrentSessionContext.html?is-external=true)  interface provided by hibernate.

By default spring sets this to the [`SpringSessionContext`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/SpringSessionContext.html) to integrate properly. In general you don't want or need to mess with the `current_session_context_class` unless you are using JTA (although when using Hibernate 4 with a recent Spring version it should also just work).

Comment: so SessionFactory.getCurrentSession is ok when using multithreading in tomcat? each thread will get his own session?